# Which msql query is faster : multiple selects or join?

Tags: mysql

Need to decide which query is faster:

Query1

```
select xyz.user, count(*) as score
from xyz join
     (select qid, min(time) as mintime
      from xyz
      group by qid
     ) q
     on xyz.qid = q.qid and xyz.time = q.mintime
group by xyz.user;
```

Query2

```
select user,count(*) 
  from (select * 
          from (select * 
                  from xyz 
                 order by time ASC
               ) as temp1 
         group by temp1.qid
        ) As temp2
  group by temp2.user
```

both return the number of times that a user is "first" for each qid.

DB:

```
CREATE TABLE xyz (
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user VARCHAR(20),
  time INT,
  qid INT
);

INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (    1  ,  'abc' ,  15  , 1);
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (    2  ,  'abc' ,  6  , 1);
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (    3  ,  'xyz' ,  11  , 1);
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (    4  ,  'abc' ,  4  , 1);
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (    5  ,  'xyz' ,  13  , 2);
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (    6  ,  'abc' ,  11  ,2);
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (    7  ,  'abc' ,  9  , 3);
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (    8  ,  'xyz' ,  10  , 3);
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (    9  ,  'xyz' ,  2  , 3);
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (    10  ,  'xyz' ,  2  , 4);
```

Edit: As suggested replaced better with faster.

Comment: Have you looked at analytical functions?

Comment: "Better" is a very vague word. What exactly do you mean by that? Faster? Less resource consuming? More maintainable? Etc, ect.

Comment: @Einar by better I mean faster

Comment: Probably a good idea to replace "better" with "faster" in the question.  Then people can help you to find tools to analyse which is faster and/or advise on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your first query contains this subquery.

```
 select qid, min(time) as mintime
   from xyz
  group by qid
```

It can be made very efficient by a compound index on `(qid,time)`. MySQL will satisfy that query with a so-called [*loose index scan.*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-optimization.html) So if I were you I would go with your first query.

But you should use `EXPLAIN` to make sure I am right. You should revisit this question sometime in the future when your tables have 100 times the number of rows they have now.

Answer (score 1):

Before anything else you should add indexes to your table on the columns you use for search or comparison:

```
ALTER TABLE `xyz`
ADD INDEX (`qid`),
ADD INDEX (`time`);
```

Then put `EXPLAIN` in front of each query and check the results against [the recommendations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html) you can find in the manual. Look closely the sections about *"Join Types"* and *"Extra Information"*.

With or without indexes, avoid the second query. It is the worst and it cannot be improved.

I propose you an alternative query that produces the same results and is even faster than your first approach:

```
SELECT uif.user, COUNT(*) AS score
FROM xyz uif                  # "uif" from "user is first"
  LEFT JOIN xyz sm            # "sm" from "smaller time"
    ON uif.qid = sm.qid AND sm.time < uif.time
WHERE sm.time IS NULL         # keep only when there is no "smaller time"
GROUP BY uif.user
```

It joins the `xyz` table (aliased as `uif`) against itself (aliased as `sm`). Each row from `uif` is paired with all the rows from `sm` that have the same `qid` and smaller times (`sm.time < uif.time`). The `LEFT JOIN` ensures that all the rows from `uif` will appear in the joined set. When a row from `uif` does not have a pair from `sm` (because there is no row in `sm` having a smaller time), the columns from `sm` are filled with `NULL`.

The `WHERE` condition keeps only these rows from `uif` that have no pair in `sm` (there is no "smaller time"); that means it keeps only the rows from `uif` that have the smaller times.

The `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses take care of your original goal (return the number of times). Always put only columns from `uid` in the `SELECT` clauses (because those of `sm` are all `NULL`, of course).

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical performance scenario regarding speed. As for any such circumstance **you have to test and measure.**

That in itself is a quite tricky task since your queries will be cached by the db engine after the first run and the following executions will be considerably faster. 
The test and measure of performance in a system needs you to consider a lot of variables to be done correctly.

**On the other side:**

My estimation is that the query with the `JOIN` would be the fastest. Modern sql DB engines are good at optimization and a `JOIN` would allow the engine to freely optimize the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user, count(*) AS score
FROM xyz JOIN
     (SELECT qid, min(time) AS mintime
      FROM xyz
      GROUP by qid
     ) q
     ON qid = q.qid AND time = q.mintime
GROUP BY user;
```

I believe `xyz.gid` and `xyz.time` is not necessary